# Python batch geocoding.py Google API: Hit Query limit

Tags: python, google-api, google-geocoding-api

[image]I'm using this python code to geocodes a batch of addresses.

https://gist.github.com/shanealynn/033c8a3cacdba8ce03cbe116225ced31

The google API says (50 requests per second (QPS) maximum).

The code is running well, its geocoding a batch of addresses and then ''Hit Query Limit! Backing off for a bit.''

I dont get it because I'm not geocoding for then 50 addresses per second.

Any ideas why I'm Hitting the query limit?

Ive created new API keys to test again, and I'm still hitting the limit.

Comment: Google also limits the maximum number of queries that can be made over a given time period, i.e. hour, 24-hour, month bases.

Comment: @e.maguire Yes 2500 querys per day for geocoding. But Ive just created a new account with another Gmail account and Im still hitting the query limit after geocoding a batch of around 100 addresses.

Comment: You could be getting throttled because they know the same machine is making the calls.

Comment: I mean I should be able to still query 2500 addresses per day? How I can overcome that?

Comment: Query limits are query limits. I would recommend adding a `sleep` call wherein you slow down the speed of the queries. If that doesn't solve the problem, you've been throttled and you have to wait for cooldown.